# How to delete entities from one-to-many collection with only composite primary keys in MariaDB

Tags: mikro-orm

```
@Entity()
export class Job {

  @PrimaryKey({ type: BigIntType })
  id: string;

  @OneToMany(() => JobExperienceLevel, 
   jobExperienceLevel => jobExperienceLevel.job, {cascade: Cascade.ALL], orphanRemoval: true})
  experienceLevels = new Collection<JobExperienceLevel>(this);

}


@Entity()
export class JobExperienceLevel {

  @PrimaryKey()
  @Enum({
    items: () => JobExperienceLevelType
  })
  experienceLevel: JobExperienceLevelType;

  @ManyToOne({nullable:false, primary: true, joinColumn: 'job_id'})
  job: Job;
}

export enum JobExperienceLevelType {
  ENTRY_LEVEL = 'ENTRY_LEVEL',
  JUNIOR = 'JUNIOR',
  REGULAR = 'REGULAR',
  SENIOR = 'SENIOR'
}
```

After calling experienceLevels.removeAll() on some job entity it is generating the following query:

```
 delete from `job_experience_level` where `experience_level` = 'SENIOR' and `job_id` is null
```

The database table 'job_experience_level' contains only composite primary keys (experience_level, job_id)

I have checked that before calling removeAll method there is one entity 'SENIOR' in the collection.

I am using entityrepository with persistAndFlush on the job entity.

The problem is that this query is wrong and it should populate the correct job_id.

I also tried to remove the @PrimaryKey() from experienceLevel property, but then there is no delete query in the transaction at all.

Comment: Can you also provide the code that leads to the error? also what does `console.log(job. experienceLevels.getItems())` print? Does the contained entity have the `job` field correctly set? The produced query is correct, it's just missing the `job` parameter value, right?

Comment: Yes. the query is correct only the job_id is wrong (should be 40 in this case). Here are some console.logs

**console.log(job.experienceLevels.getItems());** returns

 `[
   JobExperienceLevel {
  experienceLevel: 'SENIOR',
  job: Job {
    id: '40',
    title: 'test',
     ....
    }   
 ]`
 
**console.log(job.experienceLevels[0].job);** returns

 `Job {
   id: '40',
   title: 'test',
   ....
   
 }`

job.experienceLevels.removeAll();
**console.log(job.experienceLevels.getItems());** returns []

If it's not enough i can try to set up a repo with sample.

Comment: @MartinAdámek 
[Check this line](https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/blob/master/lib/entity/ArrayCollection.ts#L147)
Before line 147 item.job is correct ( is not null ) and on this line is set to null.
I'm using version 3.6.6. Here are some details:  this.property.mappedBy is 'job' and method is 'remove'

Comment: Interesting, I can try to look into this later today, looks like a bug with orphan removal and propagation. The line 147 does the propagation - if you remove item from 1:m collection, it will unset it on the m:1 side. But for prop with orphan removal enabled, I guess we should not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, there was a bug with orphan removal and composite keys. Upgrade to v3.6.7 to fix it.

https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#367-2020-04-16

Here is a testcase to make sure it really works:

https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/commit/94c71c89a648e03fad38a93cced7fa92bbfd7ff7#diff-595473b980e4d4384f667f60dbddde2aR1